# how to get total count of a particular key in local storage

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

```
var cart = { id: localStorage.length, itemid: $scope.Product.Sizeid };
            localStorage.setItem('MyCart', JSON.stringify(cart));
```

i want to get the total count of 'MyCart' in local storage. this is why in local storage another key name('User') is saved.

Comment: What count? cart is an object literal which doesn't have a count/size ... which total count EXACTLY do you want?

Comment: Please read [ask] Your question is not very clear and there is nothing related to count shown. Write a proper problem statement and explain exactly what you are trying to do and problems you are having achieving it

Comment: @devnull69 how to save an array list to local storage

Comment: You want to store an array of cart objects? Something like `cart = [{...}, {...}]`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to count the key length in local object then check the code

```
Object.keys(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('MyCart'))).length
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me a lot tonight.